# What's the difference between JNI and java wrapper for C

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javacv

I'm using JNI to accelerate my program. It's like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL SOME_FUNCTION(JNIEnv * jenv, jclass, jlong thiz)
{
  ...
}
```

Here the java program send into the c the address of the objects in the RAM, and starts the c binary.

Though I know it is really fast to execute native directly, I'm still confused at the difference between JNI and a java wrapper. Because to my understanding, the java wrapper is also working on sending in the RAM address into the C binary.

What's the intrinsic difference made them different in efficiency?

Following is an illustration that might help you answer.

By "java wrapper", I mean things like JavaCV

[image: JNI illustration]

Comment: Some wrappers sometimes help make JNI calls look more Java-like instead of being simply a direct translation. Others are just pre-made JNI interfaces.

Comment: A wrapper **is a JNI interface** that wraps C/C++ libraries to Java, by declaring native Java methods that calls C/C++ functions.

Comment: So does it mean the two are equal in performance?

Comment: "I'm using JNI to accelerate my program". "I know it is really fast to execute native directly." You're probably wrong about both those things. Crossing the JVM/JNI boundary is quite expensive. You should code the whole thing in Java first and then test and measure to see if you have a performance problem, and if so whether this is it.

Comment: @EJP Thx. I'm using computer vision algorithm on Android and the loops are really expensive in java.

Answer (score 0):

JavaCV uses JNI in its implementation.

JNI is a tool that provides a C API. JavaCV is a wrapper that exposes C APIs in a Java API using JNI.

JNI allows Java code to call native code, and vice-versa.

JavaCV makes it easy to use native computer-vision libraries from Java. If you [browse its source code](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/#git/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp), you can see that JNI native methods are used in its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper **is a JNI interface** that wraps C/C++ libraries to Java, by declaring native Java methods that calls C/C++ functions.
Moreover, JNI does not *start* a c binary, the Java Virtual Machine is the C binary that makes native calls.